# generating nice looking histogram from photo?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, photo, gnuplot, histogram

i'm currently seeking a solution for generating "nice" looking histograms from photos. i would like to have a command-line tool for linux. i know, that imagemagick can generate a histogram, which would not be that bad, but i would like to have labeled axis with the histogram.

maybe there is one tool, which can solve this or i could combine for example imagemagick and gnuplot to achieve this?

thanx very much,

Answer (score 0):

its late here so this answer is not fully complete but cimg c++ library has an example program to collect the data from the image: 
[described here](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html)

This data could then be piped to gnuplot as you suggest, either directly in the code or via a shell script as midway down this page: [http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/intro/working-e.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20101113155819/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/intro/working-e.html)

Writing code might not be what you want to do, but the cimg example is very well documented and is only about 15 lines long.  It might end up bein the quickest thing to do.

Anyway, bed time for me

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is matplotlib -- have a look [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) and [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/screenshots.html) for examples of graphs that you can create.  It does require writing a bit of code, but if you're familiar with Python, it's quite easy and straightforward.  The real benefit is flexibility -- you can customize the appearance of your histograms to fit your particular purpose.

[image: histogram in 10 lines of code]